# Logout function not clearing ParseUser currentUser in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

```
ParseUser.logOut();
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser(); // this will now be null
```

But after performing the `logOut()`, the current user is not null yet, I am consistently seeing the currentUser value in the logs. However, the session token is set to null.can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post some relevant code.

Comment: Aniruddha This is the code for logout in my app.I have used only this code. If you know other one then Please tell.

Comment: after this code `currentUser != null`? or you have some old instance code like `ParseUser currentUserBefor = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();ParseUser.logOut();ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();` and `currentUserBefor != null` ?

Comment: Selvin: yes,after this currentUser != null

Comment: I too have this issue, one way on some devices (not all) is to force the app to completely stop including the background, then cold start. This is clearly not ideal and has something to do with the local data store being enabled after some tests.